# Behaviour of belongsTo

Tags: grails, associations, grails-orm

What is the difference between

> static belongsTo [author:Author]

and

> static belongsTo = Author

Lets consider two domain class.

```
Class Author{
    String name 
}

Class Books{
    String name
    static belongsTo = Author
}
```

When **static belongsTo = Author** is kept in Books domain, it have no effects on db. However, **static belongsTo = [author : Author]** creates a backreference to Author class and also there is author_id column in db. So, what actually using **static belongsTo = Author** alone does.
This is expalined in grails docs(http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html).

Also, what is the difference between using following two :

```
Class Books{
    String name
    static belongsTo = [author : Author]
} 
Class Books{
    String name
    Author author
}
```

**static belongsTo = [author : Author]** is used only for cascading purposes, Is it true or does it have different use cases.

Can anyone explain these in detail without relating it to hasOne or hasMany. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using `belongsTo` without a back-reference is necessary for *many-to-many* associations. For example, lets assume you have the following domain classes:

```
class Book {
    String name
    Author author

    static hasMany = [categories: Category]
}

class Category {
    String name

    static hasMany = [books: Book]
}
```

If you try to use them as-is you'd get an exception like this:

*No owner defined between domain classes [class Book] and [class Category] in a many-to-many relationship. Example: static belongsTo = Category*

The solution is to make one of the domain classes the *owner* of the *many-to-many* association. Using my example, I think it makes more sense to make the `Category` the owner. However, a back-reference would not work because there could be multiple `Category`s. So, this is where a `belongsTo` without a back-reference comes in:

```
class Book {
    String name
    Author author

    static hasMany = [categories: Category]
    static belongsTo = Category
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `static belongsTo = [author: Author]` then a property named `author` of type `Author` is added to the class as a back reference. With `static belongsTo = Author` that does not happen.